# XSL values as attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="cdataStart"><![CDATA[ <![CDATA ]]></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="cdataEnd"><![CDATA[ ]] ]]></xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/Prekes">
    <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="./product">
            <product>
                    <associations>
                        <association external-reference="<xsl:value-of select="./code" />">
                            <mode>replace</mode>
                        </association>
                    </associations>
                </block>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to put my value from  into the attribute of external-reference. The problem is that I get syntax error if I try to use it like this. How can I insert it propperly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here...

```
 <association external-reference="{code}">
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

Note that you can use `xsl:attribute` here too

```
<association>
   <xsl:attribute name="external-reference">
      <xsl:value-of select="./code" />
   </xsl:attribute>
```

But as you can see, Attribute Value Templates are much more concise. You would use `xsl:attribute` in the case where you wanted the attribute to be created conditionally, for example.

Comment: Thank you, curly braces didn't helped. But I used the atribute as xsl:atribute.